Apache Iceberg - long merge time
I have AWS Glue job which is trying to merge data into Apache Iceberg table partitioned by product_id.
What i'm trying to achieve is to be able to run concurrent merge operations using AWS Glue jobs for different product_id.
Ex. example of columns to be stored
product_id, name, ... , user_id

Merge query:
existing_data.product_id = '{here_product_id}' AND new_data.product_id = existing_data.product_id AND existing_data.user_id = new_data.user_id

Saving code
merge_sql = f"""
MERGE INTO glue_catalog.default.{APACHE_ICEBERG_PREFIX}{target_path} existing_data
USING td new_data
ON existing_data.product_id = '{here_product_id}' AND new_data.product_id = existing_data.product_id AND existing_data.user_id = new_data.user_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""

spark.sql(merge_sql)

As a result i discovered that even using partitioning it took long to merge data. For concurrent executions per different product_id time is increasing.
Ex.



Jobs running
Exported rows of data
Execution times [s]




1
5k
395


4
5k
450, 420, 423, 452


8
5k
630, 628, 672, 677, 695, 613, 631, 641


1
10k
432


4
10k
628, 508, 597, 619


8
10k
840, 861, 809, 846, 882, 876, 887, 861



I have tried also Delta table format with same problem. Merge time increase a lot when there are parallel executions on same table , but different product_id
Is it possible to speedup merge time for one job execution (395[s] seems to be pretty long for 5k rows merge)? Is it possible to speedup merge time for parallel executions using different product_id? For now it's look that aws glue jobs lock/wait for each other during merge operation.

Iceberg by default uses serializable isolation type, you can change that to snapshot isolation which can update concurrently to different data files.This doesn’t lock the transaction.
Always make sure your not updating same data files otherwise update operation fails.
